# Html codes output workings as links

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DIC1.png) .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUfnq.png) this is the home page code.

need help

After writting the html codes results becomes underlined and becomes link.

why is this happening..!

need help

Comment: To have help post your code and not an image of it .

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link_decoration

Comment: Put your HTML through a validator e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your anchor tags

```html
    <a href="login.html">Login</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
```